# Insert into an external database using ajax and php : POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax

**Hello, I try to insert values into my database (in phpmyadmin) hosted by a server (gandi) but this error appear and I don't know how to resolve it
My error :**

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST 

http://95.... 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   (index):65
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
q.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
triggerMouseEvent   @   ionic.bundle.js:2953
tapClick    @   ionic.bundle.js:2942
tapMouseUp  @   ionic.bundle.js:3018
```

**My code :**

```
app.controller('ajoutUtilisateurCtrl', function($scope)
    {
      $('#submit').click(function(){
        var nom = $scope.nom;
        var prenom = $scope.prenom;
        var email = $scope.email;

        var advertisement = $('#nom').val() + $('#prenom').val() + $('#email').val();

        var datastring = {nom: nom, prenom: prenom, email: email};
        if(advertisement=='')
        {
          $('#response').html('Veuillez saisir les données');
        }
        else{
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://95.../ajoutUtilisateur.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
              $('#response').html(result);
              var advertisement = $('#nom').val("") + $('#prenom').val("") + $('#email').val("");
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
        })
      });
```

**ajoutUtilisateur.php**

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO utilisateur(nom, prenom, email) VALUES('$nom', '$prenom', '$email')";

    if($connexion->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo 'Utilisateur ajouté';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Erreur ajout utilisateur';
    }
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'db');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

    $connexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Could not connect to database");


    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo('Connexion non établie'.mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

?>
```

**How can I resolve this problem ?**

Comment: HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error). Something is wrong with your PHP script. I do not see any errors in the php code above. However you should enable errors, add this code to the top of your php script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/2906013 and btw, you should also add an `error` function to your ajax request, where you get the error response if any errors should occure (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Btw the url is not `"http://95.../ajoutUtilisateur.php"` the url you are trying to use, this has just been removed before you pasted the code here, correct?

Comment: Also, please use prepared statements. That PHP script is wide open for abuse. It seems you're already using mysqli_ so making this a prepared statement should take about 1 minute.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this.

Comment: and what does console show for js ?

Comment: Correct I removed this just before publishing my code

Comment: is it possible that a missing space would throw 500 ? `INSERT INTO utilisateur(nom` or is your file/folder '755' chmoded or other ? what's in config.php (removing credentials)

Comment: If I can give you an advice: use the $.ajax 'error' function (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in addition to the 'success' function in order to obtain more detailed messages when your request fails.

Comment: @Hulothe : please use english

Comment: @OldPadawan the syntax is correct

Comment: Ok I have another problem right now... the error is "Warning : mysqli::query() : couldn't fetch mysqli in var/www/html/.../ajoutUtilisateur.php on line 15 
Erreur ajout utilisateur""

Comment: Thank you for all your answers

Comment: @Caroline : please check [THIS](https://pastebin.com/kY5AAhmD), test it and let us know if any error thrown again

Comment: @OldPadawan There is the same error : jquery.min.js:4 POST http://95..../ajoutUtilisateur.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Caroline : there can't be **this** error using this code, as there's no call to jQuery. Check 1st if PHP is executed, then we'll check for JS error :)

Comment: @OldPadawan
Ok so when I do "echo"[ $nom / $prenom / $email ]";"  this displays well what I entered in the form.
But I have a : "Fatal error : Uncaught Error : call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in .../ajoutUtilisateur.php Stack trace : #0 {main} thrown in ... ajoutUtilisateur.php "
So the line "$stmt->bind_param("sss", $nom, $prenom, $email);" is problematic?

Comment: @Caroline : how many columns in your DB beside `nom / prenom / email` auto-increment ID I guess, but any others ?

Comment: @OldPadawan In my DB I have **10 columns** (numUtilisateur (= Auto-increment ID), login, nom, prenom, email, password, tel, civilite, adresse, profession)
But when I inserted only "nom" "prenom" "email" in my DB in **local** this has worked..

Comment: @OldPadawan can we chat elsewhere to go faster ?

Comment: @Caroline : I think you need to define all the columns in pre-prod

Comment: @Caroline : chat should open, yes we can

Comment: @OldPadawan What is the pre-prod ?

Comment: you work locally, then online pre-prod, then prod, or should be that way ^^ I see you have URL like http://IP/page.php

Comment: @OldPadawan "I have only 6 reputation, so it's not yet enough to chat" :/

Comment: give me 5/10mn, I'll set up a test script

Comment: @OldPadawan yes I have an url and I worked locally, now I want to test it online... with a server which contain my database
Ok no problem :)

Comment: @OldPadawan
Meanwhile I insert in my code all attributes but it still does not work (not surprising ^^)

Comment: @Caroline : please check [THIS](https://pastebin.com/TN4JbMdL) -> example with simple code form + treatment. Works for me. If it works for you, you'll just have to modify/improve to your needs step-by-step :) let me know

Comment: @OldPadawan Ok I will try this thank you

Comment: @OldPadawan I try your code... but this again doesn't works 
I have an alert which say the same error : "<!----> <!----> <br/> <b> Fatal error </b>: Uncaught Error: call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in ... "

Comment: @Caroline : no extra code ?! just the one I gave you ? Are table name and columns names OK ? no typo ?

Comment: @Caroline : have you/can we check `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: No extra code, only your code, no typo... I just commented all my code and try with your code... I just place my own credentials

Comment: @OldPadawan
Yes of course how can i send you this ? 
I have it on my server but I don't no if i can share you the link ^^

Comment: just create a page php.php with `<?php phpinfo(); ?> and give a link to the page (if IP/server is not a secret ^^)

Comment: So, you saw a problem ? :/

Comment: @Caroline : php7, mysql 5+, everyrhing seems to be fine to me, almost identical to servers I use, but I'm no server guru :/ I'm stuck

Comment: @OldPadawan ok nevermind I will find the problem and I would tell you :)
Thank you for all your help ^^

Comment: @Caroline : I'm officially an idiot !!! have you checked for http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php -> The prepare() method can return false and you should check for that. And I did not verify *yours* as I used one of *my tables* for testing :/

Comment: @OldPadawan How can I test the prepare() method  ?

Comment: @OldPadawan it display : Array( [0] => Array ( [errno] => 1193 [sqlstate] => HY000 [error] => Unknown system variable 'a' ) )

Comment: @Caroline : are credentials OK ? because it seems that's what error reports

Comment: @OldPadawan Yes but here I just copy the code [of the link that you share ](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php) at the end of this page

Comment: OK thought we had solved it :/ anyway you need to check the prepare method and what it returns so we make sure we can eliminate one possible option

Comment: I don't understand how check the prepare method if not like that ?

Comment: Can you please try and catch more information about errors ? Might be useful to get help from [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). You can also add column ID in the query, one thing we did not try... So, summary: you work on gandi server, online, all scripts in same folder at this time, credentials ok (no local/online mistake), no cross-domain scripting attempt : correct ?

Comment: @OldPadawan Ok I will try... 
Yes I have only mistakes online and not local and the rest I think it's correct.

Comment: @Caroline : I created a DB, same structure as yours, same columns, names, everything seems to be identical, and it works... I'll put another example in a few minutes, please test it and let me know. There's also a online example, using the script, I'll show you

Comment: @Caroline : sample with all warnings/errors reporting [HERE](https://pastebin.com/u0g757gE) -> DB table is utf8 / 1st column is INT + AI / all others are VARCHAR 250 (test IRL is [here](http://www.at-hosting.com/oldPadawan/test-gandi.php)

Comment: @OldPadawan Thank you. So, I copy your code and I obtain this error : **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php:59 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 59**
The line 59 is : **$results = $stmt1->execute();**

Comment: @Caroline: on test ot test.exe ?

Comment: @OldPadawan I don't understand ?

Comment: @Caroline: gave you 2 pages to test [HERE](https://pastebin.com/u0g757gE) : test-gandi.php and test-gandi.exe.php. maybe you can run those 2 pages on your server and see what happens (just have to use your own credentials for your server). Which one returns error ?

Comment: @OldPadawan test-gandi.php => **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php:59 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 59 The line 59 is : $results = $stmt1->execute();**

Comment: @Caroline : have you tried my online test ? as it works, with (as far as I know), same DB structure, same names and code, I'm stuck... I don't even know what this last error means :/

Comment: test-gandi.exe= > Notice: Undefined index: nom in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 53

Notice: Undefined index: prenom in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 55
[ / / ]
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 76

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_warnings() on boolean in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php:77 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/App/www/index.php on line 77

Comment: no error on test.php but ajax doesn't pass data to 2nd page... unreal ! have you tired gandi support ?

Comment: Your online test is : "http://www.at-hosting.com/oldPadawan/test-gandi.php" ?
I try and this returns me my informations : [Caroline / Caroline / caroline@gmail.com] Array () true ...
But its not with my db..

Comment: yes, so you can see DB and script are ok, therefore, ajax data isn't sent / received to/on 2nd page (I made DB with  : utf8 / 1st column is INT + AI / all others are VARCHAR 250) what is your structure ?

Comment: Yes, I called them several times but they said that I am admin of this server so they can not help me and they also said they can not fix my coding errors because they just solve problems about servers.

Comment: I made DB with "latin1_swedish_ci" / 1st column INT + AI / all others are VARCHAR between 50 and 100
"latin1_swedish_ci" causes a problem ?

Comment: we need a nice sysadmin or php guru now... :( because our DB structures look like sisters !

Comment: no way they made mistakes on credentials ? like "localhost" but it's not ?

Comment: Yes I will try to found someone like that :/

Comment: No... my user have a hostname : localhost with all privileges / grant

Comment: @Caroline : please this`$query = " INSERT INTO utilisateur (`numUtilisateur`, `login`, `nom`, `prenom`, `email`, `password`, `tel`, `civilite`, `adresse`, `profession`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  (with backticks around names, that don't show up here) ";` then `$id= ""; $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $id, $login, $nom, $prenom, $email, $pwd, $tel, $civil, $address, $prof);` and prepare query. I wonder if *your* server does not require **all** of the column names. Then, try again, with no backtick this time